# Why should Windows driver's entry name be "DriverEntry"? (Or WinMain/DllMain too)

Tags: windows, driver, entry-point

Why should Windows driver's entry name be "`DriverEntry`"? Can't Windows find the driver's entry point using the PE header or, say,  just call `main()` function to initialize the driver?

**Also**

In case of `WinMain`, too.

I think `main()` or `MainCRTSetup()`should be `main()` or `MainCRTSetup()`  unless we change the compiler setting, to let the compiler know that is the entry of our program.

However that is for compiler, isn't it? Why does Windows require the entry function name of drivers be `DriverEntry`?

Comment: it is a callback, not the entrypoint.  Further specialized by the callback being used only once so the code section that contains it is discardable.  Using non-standard names is in general a good idea when a function takes non-standard arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The people at Microsoft decided that the Entry point for a .sys file would be DriverEntry, and that is the value that gets added to the PE header.

I think they made it incompatible with a windows EXE or DLL to ensure that an exe could not be used in place of a .SYS